# How to handle Failover of MongoDB cluster in node.js server in production environment

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using mongoDB(3 node cluster) with node.js, now what would be the best practice to do when my mongoDB cluster gets down, should i stop server or stop receiving new requests and process current request and also how to retry for connecting mongoDB again.

I read about using many things like [Domain](https://nodejs.org/api/domain.html) but as it is deprecated i am in a dilemma to use it or not.

**Also what approach does most companies use in production**.

Also one more thing if my mongoDB server is down then using mongoose how to catch this error inside my queries which i have wrote using mongoose.

Below is my code how i am connecting my server with mongoDB.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var config = require('./config/database.js');
var DB_URL = config.db.url;

mongoose.connection.on("connected", function(ref) {
    console.log("Connected to " + " DB!");
});

mongoose.connection.on("error", function(err) {
    console.error('Failed to connect to DB ' + ' on startup ', err);
    if (err) {
        return next(err);
    }
});

mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', function(err) {
    console.log('Mongoose default connection to DB :' + ' disconnected');
    if (err) {
        return next(err);
    }
});

var gracefulExit = function() { 
    mongoose.connection.close(function () {
        console.log('Mongoose default connection with DB :'  + ' is disconnected through app termination');
        process.exit(0);
    });
}

process.on('SIGINT', gracefulExit).on('SIGTERM', gracefulExit);

exports.con_close = function () {
    console.log('Mongoose connection disconnected');
    mongoose.connection.close();
}

var options = {
    server: {
        socketOptions: {
            keepAlive: 1000,
            connectTimeoutMS: 30000
        }
    },
    replset: { 
        rs_name: 'replicaset',
        auto_reconnect:true,
        socketOptions: {
            keepAlive: 1000, // doubt about it
            connectTimeoutMS: 30000
        } 
    },
    user: 'root',
    pass: 'G3saGT2Y',
    auth: {
        authdb: 'admin'
    }
}

mongoose.connect(DB_URL, options, function(err) {
    console.log('ho rha hai');
    if (err) {
        console.log('error connection to mongo server!');
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

Any of you who have used mongo with node.js in production mode please tell me what approaches you have used, that could really help me for solving this situation.

Comment: I am the same person and i didn't get answer on previous question that's why i have again posted it .

Comment: Hi Prakash - you shouldn't post duplicate questions. If you didn't get an answer to your first one, then you should consider improving the question to add more useful information.